# Select datas from multiple tables using one common table in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, select

I have many tables and one common table that have ids of all these tables
for eg:

Table1

```
| ID | VALUE |       DATE |
---------------------------
|  1 |   200 | 25/04/2013 |
|  2 |   250 | 26/05/2013 |
```

Table2

```
| ID | VALUE |       DATE |
---------------------------
|  1 |   300 | 25/05/2013 |
|  2 |   100 | 12/02/2013 |
```

Table3

```
| ID | VALUE |       DATE |
---------------------------
|  1 |   500 | 5/04/2013  |
|  2 |   100 | 1/01/2013  |
```

and one common table

```
| ID |  TABLE | TABLEID |
-------------------------
|  1 | table1 |       1 |
|  2 | table3 |       1 |
|  3 | table2 |       1 |
|  4 | table1 |       2 |
|  5 | table2 |       2 |
|  6 | table3 |       2 |
```

and using this common table i need to select all datas in above 3 tables
eg:

```
output
id    table   tableid   value    date
1     table1  1         200      25/04/2013
2     table3  1         500      5/04/2013
3     table2  1         300      25/05/2013
4     table1  2         250      26/05/2013
5     table2  2         100      12/02/2013
6     table3  2         100      1/01/2013
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use `UNION ALL` you can use [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) for the same using `LEFT JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT c.* 
     , COALESCE(t1.Value, t2.Value,t3.Value) AS Value
     , COALESCE(t1.Date, t2.Date,t3.Date) AS Date
  FROM Common c
  LEFT JOIN Table1 t1 ON c.tableid = t1.[id]
   AND [Table] = 'table1'
  LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON c.tableid = t2.[id]
   AND [Table] = 'table2'
  LEFT JOIN Table2 t3 ON c.tableid = t3.[id]
   AND [Table] = 'table3'
ORDER BY ID;
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/36b46/22)

By this way you can reduce your task to join all records using `UNION ALL`. But for the given data structure you have to join all tables anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join all tables with `common` table separately then join them using `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Common c
  JOIN Table1 t1 ON c.tableid = t1.[id]
   AND [Table] = 'table1'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
  FROM Common c
  JOIN Table2 t2 ON c.tableid = t2.[id]
   AND [Table] = 'table2'
UNION ALL
SELECT *
  FROM Common c
  JOIN Table3 t3 ON c.tableid = t3.[id]
   AND [Table] = 'table3';
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/36b46/1)

Comment: the union all i already using....i need any other simple solution becuase if tables are 10 or 20 then this `union all` will difficult to work with thats why

Comment: @Suresh - Then you really need to see at your data structure. It is not ideal to add table name in other table and join them. Also you do not need to add tables for each type of record, instead add a column to separate them.

Comment: @Suresh - See [my alternative answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17857830/1369235).

Answer (score 0):

You can `UNION ALL` the tables adding flag column in the process and then JOIN the result with common table.

```
WITH CTE_Tables AS 
(
   SELECT 'Table1' AS Tab, * FROM Table1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Table2' AS Tab, * FROM Table2
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Table3' AS Tab, * FROM Table3
)
SELECT * 
FROM CommonTable c1 
LEFT JOIN CTE_Tables cte ON cte.ID = c1.TableID AND cte.Tab = c1.[Table]
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ee6d7/2)**